# Point Cloud data - learning sources

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

What are the best learning sources and study materials for Point Cloud data and [Point cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/) ?

So far I came across PCL [Documentation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/).

Comment: @Michael I've provided an answer, I hope it helps

Comment: thank you for the useful links!

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help a little bit ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [git hub](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/wiki) repository existing (which was last edited in 2013 :-( ). Maybe it helps you a little bit.
In addition there exists a [user forum](http://www.pcl-users.org/) where you can ask questions for sure.

In addition there are a few resources on the web:

- [PDF explaining the PCL (in german though)](http://wwwpub.zih.tu-dresden.de/~schwalbe/Skripte/06_Objekterkennung/Tutorial_PCL_BerndGrafe.pdf)
- [Another PDF explaining PCL](http://www.jeffdelmerico.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/pcl_tutorial.pdf)
- [Tutorial for PCL](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials),
- [Another Tutorial for PCL](http://robotica.unileon.es/mediawiki/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_tutorial_2:_Cloud_processing_%28basic%29),

Comment: btw, did you stumble upon any interesting materials on Point registration (with or without reference points) ? thx

Answer (score 1):

This [PDF](http://www.jeffdelmerico.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/pcl_tutorial.pdf) is best to understand Point cloud.

And The [documentation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/) you mention is good if you know the basic flow.So My opinion is to start with given [PDF](http://www.jeffdelmerico.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/pcl_tutorial.pdf) and then continue with official [documentation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/).

That exactly what I am doing :)